# Google Drive API - Service account w/ domain-wide authority can list shared drives but not their contents

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, service-accounts

##### *Note: I am *not* using a Cloud Client Library, and instead am using the Google Drive API via Powershell and HTTP, [going against the guides recommendations](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#overview).*

---

I am trying to have a Powershell script do a simple upload of a file using the Google Drive API (v3). My current GCP project includes a service account that has been granted domain-wide authority with the following scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`

Following the "*[Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests)*" guide, I have successfully created a JWT, used said JWT to get an access token, and use said access token to interact with the API. I have also confirmed that the service account is able to successfully "impersonate" a user account in our Workspace (using the `sub` parameter in the "*Additional claims*" section of the guide above).

The issue I am facing is regarding permissions. I get a successful response back from `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives` and can see the Shared Drives that the impersonated-user has access to. However, I get a `(403) Forbidden` when requesting to list the contents of one of these Shared Drives; specifically via `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?driveId=<DRIVE_ID_HERE>?includeItemsFromAllDrives=true?supportsAllDrives=true?corpora=allDrives`.

Is there an issue with my request parameters? I'm confused as to why a user with Content Manager access to a Shared Drive is able to list Shared Drives and not any contents within said drives?

---

##### Edit 1: added snippets for 1) building JWT & access token and 2) Google Drive API requests

###### JWT & Access Token

```
$now = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$createDate = [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date($now) -UFormat '%s'))
$expiryDate = [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date($now.AddHours(1)) -UFormat '%s'))

$payload = [Ordered]@{
    iss = 'service_account@xyz-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    sub = 'account-user@gmail.com'
    scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    aud = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
    iat = $createDate
    exp = $expiryDate
} | ConvertTo-Json

$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", 'pw')

# link to JWT module is in OP
$jwt = New-Jwt -PayloadJson $payload -Cert $cert -Verbose

$accessTokenResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' `
    -UseBasicParsing `
    -Method 'POST' `
    -Headers @{'Content-Type' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} `
    -Body "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=$jwt" `
    -Verbose
$accessToken = ($accessTokenResponse.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
```

###### Request to [drives-list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list)

```
$uploadResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives' `
    -UseBasicParsing `
    -Method 'GET' `
    -Headers @{'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken"'} `
    -Verbose
```

###### Request to [files-list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

```
# Using driveId in the response from drives-list above
$uploadResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?driveId=<DRIVE_ID_HERE>?includeItemsFromAllDrives=true?supportsAllDrives=true?corpora=allDrives' `
    -UseBasicParsing `
    -Method 'GET' `
    -Headers @{'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken"'} `
    -Verbose
```

The `403` response I get back from the files-list request is:

```
PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          : System.Net.HttpWebRequest
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\...\GDriveAPITest.ps1: line 80
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

---

##### Edit 2: added snippet to determine if impersonation is working

After reviewing answers/comments, I wanted to confirm if impersonation is working in my existing code. In the snippets above in Edit 1, I am passing in the account-to-impersonate in the `sub` param during access token creation. This step is outline in the docs, [under Additional claims in the HTTP/REST guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

I then did a `GET` to [about-get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) to determine if the impersonation is working with the access token.

###### Request to about-get

```
$uploadResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=*' `
    -UseBasicParsing `
    -Method 'GET' `
    -Headers @{'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken"; 'Content-Type' = 'text/plain'} `
    -Verbose
```

###### Response from about-get (in JSON)

```json
{
  "kind": "drive#about",
  "user": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "Impersonated User",
    "photoLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/default-user=s64",
    "me": true,
    "permissionId": "<PERMISSION_ID_HERE>",
    "emailAddress": "impersonated_user@gmail.com"
  },
  "storageQuota": { ... },
  "importFormats": { ... },
  "exportFormats": { ... },
  "maxImportSizes": { ... },
  "maxUploadSize": "0000000000000",
  "appInstalled": false,
  "folderColorPalette": [ ... ],
  "teamDriveThemes": [ ... ],
  "driveThemes": [ ... ],
  "canCreateTeamDrives": true,
  "canCreateDrives": true
}
```

Does this confirm that I have impersonation working?

The impersonated user is a `Content Manager` on the Shared Drive and the Drive SDK is enabled in the org/project. The next update I am trying is to confirm all scopes needed by the Drive API endpoint(s) are assigned to the service account *and* the JWT token. Will report back after updating.

Comment: Edit your question to include one complete reproducible example using PowerShell and include the complete return response. Check if the account you are impersonating has access to the drive contents. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated the OP with snippets. Thx for commenting - I hope there's some helpful context there now; happy to provide more as needed.

Comment: 1/2) Your JWT code is creating an OAuth Access Token (good). However, your code is not performing the **impersonation** step. That is why you are getting the 403 error as the credentials are the service account's identity and not a user's identity. I wrote an article on impersonation using PowerShell. Maybe my code examples will help you. Review my function **Impersonate-GoogleServiceAccount**:  Note: my example takes a **user**'s access token and impersonates a **service account**. You will want to do the opposite, but the impersonation logic is the same.

Comment: 2/2) Replace the service account email address with the user's email address:  https://www.jhanley.com/powershell-impersonate-google-service-account/

Comment: Awesome, thanks John. Your guide is a great help. I am getting a 403 in the impersonation step now, but maybe because I have not given the user account the IAM permission to generate access tokens (`iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken`) for the service account? I also have not given my service account's scope to include [the scopes needed for the impersonation endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken). I will update the the IAM and scopes for both accounts and report back.

Comment: Hey John, thanks again for all the help. Please take a peek at Edit 2 if you have a min. If impersonation is working there, then would my next best bet be regarding scopes assigned to the service account and JWT token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Fernando, John, and ale13 for your comments!

I was able to confirm that I was getting a *(403) Forbidden* from the files-list endpoint on a Shared Drive due to an issue with the user account being impersonated.

- In my service account setup, I have domain-wide delegation enabled
- With my JWT and access token creation, I have impersonation setup correctly
- I have the Drive API enabled on my project
- In my service account and token creation, I have full-scope set with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- The user account being impersonated is a valid member of the Workspace and is added to the Shared Drive

However, the user account in our Workspace in which the service account was impersonating was not completely set up correctly. I was seeing a 403 on files-list on the Shared Drive root because the user account did *not* have access to all contents under the Shared Drive root. The user account's access was updated and the endpoint returned at 200 as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)? Even if the impersonation and everything may be correct, without domain wide delegation the service account does not get enough permissions and can show this error.

Answer modification:
The problem is actually related to the user impersonation as it is not being performed correctly in the code.

Comment: Hey Fernando, thanks for responding. I think I might have misspoke in my question in regards to domain-wide "authority" instead of "delegation". I can confirm that I have enabled my service account with domain-wide delegation with the following scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`

Comment: What about using the service account directly and just add it to the shared drive? Service accounts have access to Google Drive as well with the same limits of gmail.com accounts, although they do not have a web UI to use it.

Comment: I can confirm that both the service account and impersonated Workspace account are apart of the Shared Drive (with the Content Manager role), so unfortunately no luck there. I do appreciated any ideas/help tho, since I'm not sure what other permission-issues could possibly be giving me a 403 at this point.

Comment: I think there are many things that still need to be checked at this point, so it would be better to narrow down the issue. Can you share the API methods that you are using, for example, the drives list or drives get from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference

Comment: I would also recommend checking who is doing the API call in the project. You may be authenticating with the user and the service account, however you may be running the API using a different account.

Comment: Thanks again for following up Fernando. I have updated the question with some snippets that hopefully provide the context needed. I have not confirmed that the account running the API is matching the impersonated user that the service account is using - will do so now and check back shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think the problem may be related to the domain wide delegation as you need to add all the scopes that each method would use and so far you mentioned you only added 2 scopes. Make sure to add all the scopes from the list of each method that appears in the documentation of each one.

Comment: Your comments are on the right track. With the new edit, I can see that the code is creating an access token from the service account but not completing the **impersonation** step. Modify your answer so that I can upvote.

Comment: Hey guys, just bumping to let you know I've updated OP with Edit 2, where I (try to) confirm that impersonation is in fact working. Please check it out if you have a minute, and thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

#### Creating a service account is not enough and performing domain wide delegation is not enough in this situation. You also have to impersonate another user in your domain.

The main purpose of granting domain-wide authority to a *service account* and later using impersonation is for these accounts to be able to access data on behalf of a user in your domain as otherwise the *service account* acts like just another account and it is trying to access its own data from Drive.

If the problem occurs at the impersonation part, you might want to double check if the scope/s set in the code match the ones you granted for the service account.

So for instance, these scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`,  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` should be added to the service account as well.

However, since you are trying to access a shared drive, the following might also cause a `403`:

- Drive SDK is not enabled for your organization;
- The user you are impersonating does not in fact have access to the shared and/or cannot retrieve the files from it;

In this case it would be useful to check the permissions which have been granted to the actual user for this shared drive.

#### Reference

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority);
- [Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation);
- [Resolve Drive API errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/handle-errors).

Comment: Hey ale13, thanks for answering, I appreciate the help. I just updated OP with Edit 2 that may/may not confirm that impersonation is in fact working, and that the 403 could be coming from elsewhere. Just to confirm, the impersonated-user does have Content Manager access to the Shared Drive, and the Drive SDK is enabled.

Comment: Have you tried making a different request within Drive?

Comment: I have, yeah. I'm able to 200 with files-create with my current scopes and token setup. So with files-create working and files-list failing, I was thinking it could be that I am missing the needed scopes for files-list. I need to confirm this, but at the same time, shouldn't `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` be enough scope for that endpoint?